# Working with a StructType column in PySpark UDF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have the following schema for one of columns that I'm processing,

```
 |-- time_to_resolution_remainingTime: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _links: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- self: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- completedCycles: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- breached: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- elapsedTime: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- friendly: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- millis: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- goalDuration: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- friendly: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- millis: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- remainingTime: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- friendly: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- millis: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- startTime: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- epochMillis: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- friendly: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- iso8601: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- jira: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- stopTime: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- epochMillis: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- friendly: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- iso8601: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- jira: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ongoingCycle: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- breachTime: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- epochMillis: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- friendly: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- iso8601: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- jira: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- breached: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- elapsedTime: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- friendly: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- millis: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- goalDuration: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- friendly: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- millis: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- paused: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- remainingTime: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- friendly: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- millis: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- startTime: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- epochMillis: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- friendly: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- iso8601: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- jira: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- withinCalendarHours: boolean (nullable = true)
```

I'm interested in getting the time fields (e.g completedCycles[x].elapsedTime, ongoingCycle.remainingTime) etc, based on certain conditions. The UDF I'm using is:

```py
@udf("string")
def extract_time(s, field):
  # Return ongoing cycle field
  if has_column(s, 'ongoingCycle'):
    field = 'ongoingCycle.{}'.format(field)
    return s[field]
  
  # return last element of completed cycles
  s = s.get(size(s) - 1)
  return s[field]

cl = 'time_to_resolution_remainingTime'
df = df.withColumn(cl, extract_time(cl, lit("elapsedTime.friendly"))).select(cl)
display(df)
```

This results in an error:

```py
SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 549.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 549.0 (TID 1597, 10.155.239.76, executor 0): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1514, in __getitem__
    idx = self.__fields__.index(item)
ValueError: 'ongoingCycle.elapsedTime.friendly' is not in list
```

I'm obviously doing something terribly wrong here, but I'm unable to resolve this. Is it possible to convert the `s` data frame in the UDF to a python dictionary and perform calculations on that? or is there a much better way to do this?

**Edit:**

Sample Data

```json
{
   "_links":{
      "self":"https:///...."
   },
   "completedCycles":[
      
   ],
   "id":"630",
   "name":"Time to resolution",
   "ongoingCycle":{
      "breachTime":{
         "epochMillis":1605583651354,
         "friendly":"17/Nov/20 3:27 PM +12:00",
         "iso8601":"2020-11-17T15:27:31+1200",
         "jira":"2020-11-17T15:27:31.354+1200"
      },
      "breached":true,
      "elapsedTime":{
         "friendly":"57h 32m",
         "millis":207148646
      },
      "goalDuration":{
         "friendly":"4h",
         "millis":14400000
      },
      "paused":false,
      "remainingTime":{
         "friendly":"-53h 32m",
         "millis":-192748646
      },
      "startTime":{
         "epochMillis":1605511651354,
         "friendly":"16/Nov/20 7:27 PM +12:00",
         "iso8601":"2020-11-16T19:27:31+1200",
         "jira":"2020-11-16T19:27:31.354+1200"
      },
      "withinCalendarHours":false
   }
}

Expected output: -53h 23m
```

With completed cycles but no ongoing cycle

```json
{
   "_links":{
      "self":"https://...."
   },
   "completedCycles":[
      {
         "breached":true,
         "elapsedTime":{
            "friendly":"72h 43m",
            "millis":261818073
         },
         "goalDuration":{
            "friendly":"4h",
            "millis":14400000
         },
         "remainingTime":{
            "friendly":"-68h 43m",
            "millis":-247418073
         },
         "startTime":{
            "epochMillis":1605156449463,
            "friendly":"12/Nov/20 4:47 PM +12:00",
            "iso8601":"2020-11-12T16:47:29+1200",
            "jira":"2020-11-12T16:47:29.463+1200"
         },
         "stopTime":{
            "epochMillis":1606282267536,
            "friendly":"Today 5:31 PM +12:00",
            "iso8601":"2020-11-25T17:31:07+1200",
            "jira":"2020-11-25T17:31:07.536+1200"
         }
      }
   ],
   "id":"630",
   "name":"Time to resolution",
   "ongoingCycle": null
}

Expected output: -68h 43m
```

I got this code to work but not sure if it's the best way to go about solving this,

```py
@udf("string")
def extract_time(s, field):
  if s is None:
    return None
  
  # Return ongoing cycle field
  if has_column(s, 'ongoingCycle'):
    if s['ongoingCycle'] is not None:
      return s['ongoingCycle']['remainingTime']['friendly']
    
  # Get the last completed cycles' remaining time
  s_completed = s['completedCycles']
  if len(s_completed) > 0:
    return s_completed[-1]['remainingTime']['friendly']
  return None
```

Comment: if you only have struct, you can access a column with "column1.columnA" where 1 is the parent of A.  i do not see why you want to use an UDF. UDF is for data manupulation, not structure manipulation.

Comment: can you show data sample and expected output ?

Comment: @Steven Added sample data and the UDF code which is giving the expected output

Comment: Spark Version ?

Comment: I'm using spark 2.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `when` function to check same logic as you have implemented in `UDF`.

Check below code.

```
df.show()
+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|_links         |completedCycles                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |id |name              |ongoingCycle                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[https:///....]|[]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |630|Time to resolution|[[1605583651354, 17/Nov/20 3:27 PM +12:00, 2020-11-17T15:27:31+1200, 2020-11-17T15:27:31.354+1200], true, [57h 32m, 207148646], [4h, 14400000], false, [-53h 32m, -192748646], [1605511651354, 16/Nov/20 7:27 PM +12:00, 2020-11-16T19:27:31+1200, 2020-11-16T19:27:31.354+1200], false]|
|[https://....] |[[true, [72h 43m, 261818073], [4h, 14400000], [-68h 43m, -247418073], [1605156449463, 12/Nov/20 4:47 PM +12:00, 2020-11-12T16:47:29+1200, 2020-11-12T16:47:29.463+1200], [1606282267536, Today 5:31 PM +12:00, 2020-11-25T17:31:07+1200, 2020-11-25T17:31:07.536+1200]]]|630|Time to resolution|null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


df.withColumn("time_to_resolution_remainingTime",F.expr("CASE WHEN ongoingCycle IS NOT NULL THEN ongoingCycle.elapsedTime.friendly WHEN size(completedCycles) > 0 THEN completedCycles[size(completedCycles)-1].remainingTime.friendly ELSE null END"))\ 
.select("time_to_resolution_remainingTime")\ 
.show(false)

+--------------------------------+
|time_to_resolution_remainingTime|
+--------------------------------+
|57h 32m                         |
|-68h 43m                        |
+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: however there's another condition to check if `ongoingCycle` is present in the column list, I believe the expresseion you shared assumes that column exists.

Comment: yes, it will check if column exist and not null .. spark will add null if column is not exist in any of the rows.

Comment: Hmmm, I ran this but it gave an error `"cannot resolve '`ongoingCycle`' given input columns:[.....]`

Comment: how you executed ? with one record which ongoingCycle is not there in that record ?.. in this case better define your own schema and add to data .. if column is not available in data spark will add null to that column.

Comment: I had defined an incorrect schema, thanks this worked! :)