# PySpark: Reading a JSON file with defined fixed types for only certain fields

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a requirement in which certain fields of JSON file need to be of Struct type for my transformations to work, else I get an error - `Can't extract value from <field>; need struct type but got string`

The implicit schema by spark isn't useful here since the values of the field in question can be null throughout the JSON file, hence spark assumes it's of string type. I don't want to define my own schema here since there are a large number of fields (> 1000) and it's only few fields where I require the type to be forced on.

I tried casting the field after reading the file but I get an error `due to data type mismatch: cannot cast string to struct<>`

Edit:
You can refer this [Working with a StructType column in PySpark UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65007134/working-with-a-structtype-column-in-pyspark-udf) for more details on the transformation that I'm working on.

A very high level schema,

```
- root:
  - a_time:
    - time_to_resolution_remainingTime
     ....
  - b_time:
    - time_to_resolution_remainingTime
    ....
```

In my use case, it is possible for the `a_time` field to be completely null leading to a spark assigning it a string type.

```json
...
{
   "name":"time_to_resolution",
      "nullable":true,
      "type":{
        "fields":[
          {
            "metadata":{
              
            },
            "name":"_links",
            "nullable":true,
            "type":{
              "fields":[
                {
                  "metadata":{
                    
                  },
                  "name":"self",
                  "nullable":true,
                  "type":"string"
                }
              ],
              "type":"struct"
            }
          },
          {
            "metadata":{
              
            },
            "name":"completedCycles",
            "nullable":true,
            "type":{
              "containsNull":true,
              "elementType":{
                "fields":[
                  {
                    "metadata":{
                      
                    },
                    "name":"breached",
                    "nullable":true,
                    "type":"boolean"
                  },
                  {
                    "metadata":{
                      
                    },
                    "name":"elapsedTime",
                    "nullable":true,
                    "type":{
                      "fields":[
                        {
                          "metadata":{
                            
                          },
                          "name":"friendly",
                          "nullable":true,
                          "type":"string"
                        },
                        {
                          "metadata":{
                            
                          },
                          "name":"millis",
                          "nullable":true,
                          "type":"long"
                        }
                      ],
                      "type":"struct"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "metadata":{
                      
                    },
                    "name":"goalDuration",
                    "nullable":true,
                    "type":{
                      "fields":[
                        {
                          "metadata":{
                            
                          },
                          "name":"friendly",
                          "nullable":true,
                          "type":"string"
                        },
                        {
                          "metadata":{
                            
                          },
                          "name":"millis",
                          "nullable":true,
                          "type":"long"
                        }
                      ],
                      "type":"struct"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "metadata":{
                      
                    },
                    "name":"remainingTime",
                    "nullable":true,
                    "type":{
                      "fields":[
                        {
                          "metadata":{
                            
                          },
                          "name":"friendly",
                          "nullable":true,
                          "type":"string"
                        },
                        {
                          "metadata":{
                            
                          },
                          "name":"millis",
                          "nullable":true,
                          "type":"long"
                        }
                      ],
                      "type":"struct"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "metadata":{
                      
                    },
                    "name":"startTime",
                    "nullable":true,
                    "type":{
                      "fields":[
                        {
                          "metadata":{
                            
                          },
                          "name":"epochMillis",
                          "nullable":true,
                          "type":"long"
                        },
                        {
                          "metadata":{
                            
                          },
                          "name":"friendly",
                          "nullable":true,
                          "type":"string"
                        },
                        {
                          "metadata":{
                            
                          },
                          "name":"iso8601",
                          "nullable":true,
                          "type":"string"
                        },
                        {
                          "metadata":{
                            
                          },
                          "name":"jira",
                          "nullable":true,
                          "type":"string"
                        }
                      ],
                      "type":"struct"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "metadata":{
                      
                    },
                    "name":"stopTime",
                    "nullable":true,
                    "type":{
                      "fields":[
                        {
                          "metadata":{
                            
                          },
                          "name":"epochMillis",
                          "nullable":true,
                          "type":"long"
                        },
                        {
                          "metadata":{
                            
                          },
                          "name":"friendly",
                          "nullable":true,
                          "type":"string"
                        },
                        {
                          "metadata":{
                            
                          },
                          "name":"iso8601",
                          "nullable":true,
                          "type":"string"
                        },
                        {
                          "metadata":{
                            
                          },
                          "name":"jira",
                          "nullable":true,
                          "type":"string"
                        }
                      ],
                      "type":"struct"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "type":"struct"
              },
              "type":"array"
            }
          }
```

Another field with same structure but assigned as string due to all null values.

```json
{
      "metadata":{
        
      },
      "name":"time_to_resolution_b",
      "nullable":true,
      "type":"string"
}
```

Comment: I don't have any sample data to share, it's mostly about casting a field to struct which are all nulls (at times) and spark implicitly treats it as string

Comment: The number of fields with in that struct aren't fixed

Comment: Hmm, I'm able to use a UDF for transformation and it works alright. But if I try to use the SQL equivalent transformation it throws an error. I guess in this case I'll have to go with a UDF.

Comment: I'm working with the same transformation as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65007134/working-with-a-structtype-column-in-pyspark-udf which you had answered. The only difference is that field `time_to_resolution` is present under multiple other fields which can at times be completely null.

Comment: But the problem is spark implicitly assigns the entire field a string type when the "time_to_resolution" column values are null. However, sql expression "case when... then..." expects a struct type element leading to the above mentioned error.

Comment: Added a highlevel schema to the question

Comment: The data is always of struct type when it comes in, but it can be all nulls the other time. I can't define a schema for this as it's dynamic in nature.

Comment: can you post your schema in json format .. ```df.schema.json``` also which fields do you want to access ?

Comment: Added the complete schema

Comment: can also add which fields do you want from in this schema ?

Comment: One thing I would suggest is to filter the ones with the proper struct data and then cast it and append back to the original df later.

Comment: Hmm, I ended up using the UDF as it was much simpler development wise.